# Performing queries in laravel relationships

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-table

I'm using laravel relationships to eager load some data like below

```
$domains = Domains::with('customer:id,Name');
```

The relation is defined by below

```
public function customer()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Customers::class, 'customer_id', 'id');
}
```

The data returned is used to populate a bootstrap table. the data looks like below

```
{"total": 25,
    "rows": [{
    "id":1,
    "domain_name":"RandomDomain",
    "customer_id":1,
    "customer":
        {"id":1,
        "Name":"Customer Name"}},...]
}
```

I'm now trying to perform sorting queries where when I click on table header it sends the header name to sort by. If i click on the header for customer name it will send "customer.Name" which I'll need to use to sort the data. But I can't do a straight `orderBy('customer.Name', 'ASC')` because this is eager loaded. I know joins can be used to do this. But I'm wondering if there is a way to do this using relationships?

Comment: No. Sorting is performed by a database, that's why the columns that are used in sorting should be joined in the query.

Comment: that's what I thought. But just wanted to know if there was a way to do it that I didnt know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, check the spelling of the table name

```
return $domains = Domains::join('customers', 'domains.customer_id', '=', 'customers.id')
->orderBy('customers.Name', 'ASC')->get();
```